# Is there a way to edit default build settings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, build-settings

Every time I create a new project in Delphi 2009, it loads up two sets of build settings: Debug and Release.  Problem is, the Debug settings are all wrong.  It has optimizations on, which makes the debugger lose local variables, and Debug DCUs off, which keeps me from tracing into the VCL.

Is there any way to edit the original template so I don't have to keep changing those two settings every time I create a new project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up the Debug configuration you want using Project|Options, and then check the "Default" button at the lower left of that dialog before saving your changes. That makes those settings the default ones for all new projects.

Note that checking the Default button will *not* affect existing projects; it only affects new projects you create from that point on.

Comment: It probably worth noting that the "default" check box has been available for many versions, at least as far back as Delphi 4, probably even earlier.

Comment: I should have mentioned that for future readers. I think it's been around since Delphi 3 at least (maybe 2, even).